# Unable to install NeoFetch

Tags: software-installation

[image]

I am simply attempting to install `Neofetch` in Ubuntu 20.04, but the above image shows that I am unable to. What should I do? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do the upgrade and fix the issues there before attempting to install neofetch. You could start with the `apt --fix-broken install` as it suggests.  Also, consider pasting your text into your questions, screenshots are annoying.

Comment: Please don't provide pictures of text (copy & paste the text into your question yourself), I can't copy & paste from a picture to explore your errors.. Since you have access to the text, you can explore the issue yourself, but `neofetch` does work in *focal* or 20.04.

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable `universe` repository to install the missing dependencies:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
```